# wkhtmltopdf renders html file in wrong font

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, fonts, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf tool to convert HTML file into pdf.

A document may contains Burmese characters (zawgyi font) and because of that when the tool creates the pdf, the file contains a wrong chars (black squares)

the solution for this was to copy zawgyi.ttf font file into /user/share/font

in the sandbox ubuntu (16.04) the file was rendered as expected.

but when I tried this in the production server (ubuntu 14.04) I got a wrong chars

[image]

the right one is the true one, but the left one is the wrong rendering.

I feel like there is a different config in ubuntu font

Any help to get this work in the production server?

Comment: Are you still having this problem? Are you able to provide links to source and `pdf` files for examination?